# jQuery keyup get all the characters pressed at a time

Tags: jquery, keyup

How can I get all the character pressed at a time? I have a timer of 500 ms and I want to get all the characters pressed within. Lets say I have pressed "asd" very fast, then I want to use "asd" as a search string, not just "d". Here is my idea:

```
    var mytimer;
    $filter_container.on('keyup',function(key){
        // getting key from ascii
        var mykey = get_key_from_ascii(key);

        clearTimeout(mytimer);
        var $item = $(this);
        var $item2 = this;
        var ms = 500; // milliseconds
        mytimer = setTimeout(function() {
            // here i want to send the whole character set to search
            my_auto_complete($item, key, $item2);
        }, ms);
    });
```

Comment: try using `input` or `keypress` instead of `keyup`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
var mytimer;
var collectedKeys = [];

$filter_container.on('keyup',function(key){
    // getting key from ascii
    var mykey = get_key_from_ascii(key);

    // push key to array of keys
    collectedKeys.push(mykey);

    my_auto_complete($item, collectedKeys, $item2);

});

// after 500 ms, clear keys array
mytimer = setTimeout(function() {
        collectedKeys = [];
    }, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you. It resets the timer every time a key is pressed and by enclosing the timer var in a function expression, you are limiting its scope. It also checks for an empty input and will run if somebody clicks outside before the 500ms.

[image]

```
(function () {

    var timer = 0,
        input = $('#search'),
        label = $('#search-label');

    function checkSearch() {
        var val = input.val();

        if (val) {
            doSearch(val);
        } else {
            label.text('');
        }
    }

    function doSearch(val) {
        label.text('Searching for ' + val);
    }

    input.on('keyup', function (e) {
        if (timer) {
            clearTimeout(timer);
        }
        timer = setTimeout(checkSearch, 500);
    });

    input.blur(function () {
        checkSearch();
    });

})();
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/z9bh5jc2/)

Answer (score 0):

No need to set a time interval for calling the auto complete functionality, you can simply get the returned value on keyup and send it to the auto complete function.

```js
$("#kad").on('keyup',function(){
    
    $("#text").html($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="kad" /> 

<p id="text"> </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

keyUp is called every time a different key is pressed. You will need to concatenate all the keys pressed into an array or a string as you wish below is the code:

```
var str="";
var mytimer;
    $('body').on('keyup',function(e){
        // getting key from ascii

        str = str + String.fromCharCode(e.which);

        mytimer = setTimeout(function() {
            // here i want to send the whole character set to search
           alert(str);
        }, 500);
    });
```

I have tested the [Fiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/m725frL8/) Click on the bottom right pane and press few keys to check